# Conflict between Rails Admin and Impressionist gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm using the latest version of the Impressionist and Rails Admin gems, and wondering if anyone could shed some light on an annoying conflict I'm experiencing. The problem is roughly documented here - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1315, yet the vaguely described solution is not working for me. When I have the line is_impressionable in my Listing model, I get an error when starting my Rails server with rails s:

```
    ...rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `is_impressionable' for Listing(no database connection):Class (NameError)
```

If I first start the server, and then add the 'is_impressionable' line, everything works fine, so the problem only occurs during initialization. I don't fully understand the initialization process, so am not sure how to go about getting this to work.

I have tried moving all my rails_admin model configuration options to their respective models, rather than in the initializer, which had no effect. I also have the following line in my initializer:

```
    config.included_models = [Listing,ListingImage,AllOtherModelsHere...]
```

I have tried adding single quotes around these model names, which results in the following errors, as described in the github issue [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1315)

```
    [RailsAdmin] Could not load model Listing, assuming model is non existing. (undefined local variable or method `is_impressionable' for Listing(no database connection):Class)
```

Any ideas what else I can try to make these gems work together? I don't want to have to remove the is_impressionable line every time I want to restart the server or generate a migration...

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Nope, see below. To get around it I'm not using 'is_impressionable' - this means I have to manually log views in my controller

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the same issue that I had but yet I will post what worked for me just in case someone struggles with this too:

Im on a ruby 2.1.5 project with rails 4.2.0 and among other gems I'm using rails admin.
I run into several weird problems trying to set this up. For instance if I added the `is_impressionable` call within one of my models for some reason the execution of that file stopped there and I started getting weird errors like any method declared below the is_impressionable failed with undefined error.
So what I end up doing was:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Impressionist::IsImpressionable
  is_impressionable
end
```

So this solved my issue and now i can access `@my_model_instance.impression_count` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I changed every occurrence of `Klass` to `'Klass'.constantize` in initializer.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work for me. I changed it to config.included_models = ['Article'.constantize,'Listing'.constantize] in my rails admin initializer, then added the 'is_impressionable' line in my listing model, and I get the same error I described initially